# Why XmlHttpRequest is sent though ClientValidation is failed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jquery-validate

I have many AJAX forms on the page and on button click I need to submit them all. Regular **forms.each(function (index, form) { $(form).submit();} won't work for me because in this way ONLY the last form will be submitted eventually. Therefore, I need submit them via $.ajax(...). But I want to enable submit ONLY and ONLY if form is VALID

On "submitForms" click the function "submitTest" is invoked.
From jQuery documantation "submitHandler" would be called if form is VALID.
So, the validation works and "submitHandler" is NOT invoked if form is INVALID. BUT, the XmlHttpRequest is sent anyway, though "submitHandler" isn't invoked.

Where is my mistake? Or is there other way to do it?
Thank you

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("FormPost", "Customer", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "form-container" }))
       { %>

            <%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name, new { width = 440, height = 100 })%>
             <input type="button" value="submitForms" />
    <% }%>


<script type="text/javascript">
function submitTest(){
var forms = $(".form-container");

forms.each(function (index, form) {
    $(form).validate({
         submitHandler: function (form) {
                 $.ajax(
                 { 
                    ....
                 });
         }
    });
});

forms.each(function (index, form) {
     $(form).submit();
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

Most likely it's due to the Ajax.BeginForm as that sets up an onclick and an onsubmit handler.  Which probably winds up triggering first before your validate submit handler.

**UPDATE**
If you want to keep using the ajax form in the module where you plan on submitting the form via `jQuery.ajax`, you can do the following.

```
$(function() {
   $('.form-container').removeAttr('onsubmit').removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

This will remove the handlers Ajax.BeginForm puts on the `form` tag. You'll need a way to not include this script in the other module though.

Comment: BUT, I initiate validate before it and therefore on $(form).submit() $(form).validate() should be triggered and ONLY if the form is VALID it will be submitted, isn't it?

Comment: So, how I can fix this. I want to remain "<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("FormPost", "Customer", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "form-container" }))" and also to use validate. How I do it?

Comment: I UPDATED my question. Please help me with it. This is vary urgent for me.

Comment: @user573082 why do you need it to remain Ajax.BeginForm if you're submitting the form via jQuery's $.ajax call anyway?

Comment: 1st of all, this help me to save action method for the form. Because this module can be in different modules. It's kind dynamic module. If it inside 1st module, so the request is sent via $.ajax and if it inside 2nd module, so the request will be sent by clicking on the hidden submit button.